# Kibana search in JSON field as string in APM logs

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elastic-apm

I have Elasticsearch + APM + Kibana configured for my services. Every http request is traced to APM. I'm currently capturing the body of all request. The field which stores the body inside the apm index is http.request.body.original.

The field look like this:

[image]

The problem is that I can't search inside that field. Something like http.request.body.original : *testuser* doesn't work. The body could be a simple JSON. Is there a way to allow searching in that fields? I need to prepare a dashboard with the requests that contains a specific user inside the body.

[image]

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Http mapping image of apm-*transaction* index
[image]

Comment: Can you show the response of this call `GET your-index/mapping/field/http.request.body.original` ? it shows as searchable, but I think it's not

Comment: The endpoint returns empty value. Here is an image of the http mapping. It's weird because in APM view inside Kibana, I see an http.request.body.original field with its post value as JSON but the mapping is not showing it.

Comment: You should search on `http.request.body.content` or `http.request.body.content.text`